# Converting Rigify Rig To/From 2.79 and 2.93

Tags: python, rigify

I have a Rigify Rig I created in 2.79.  If I open that file in 2.93, the bones and constraints and all that work correctly, but the buttons do not.  The IK2FK and FK2IK, etc.

I understand that this has to do with the differences in the blender python language between 2.79 and >2.80.

Is there some way to update the Rigify script attached to this file, to a 2.93 version of the script?  If I append the Rigify Rig, will it be updated?

Also, would there be a way to convert a Rigify rig from 2.93 back to 2.79? (by some miracle :X)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go through the py files in your blend scene and see if there is a rig_ui.py. If there is try to run it and see if that solves the problem.

There is another approach but only if you still have the metarig. You can re-generate it and it will update the rig to the currently available features. The underlying rig types in the meta rig are most likely still the same.

Keep in mind that the 2.93 generated rig may be quite different from the old one so your existing animations or even the weight binding may not work.

Comment: i have the ui.py that goes with the rig, but i think that only draws the buttons.  that script runs fine.
  the buttons are all there (even without running that script), but pressing them throws an error in the ui.py that's in the rigify addon directory.
https://prnt.sc/CAqS7CUAQXfY

i see 'thigh_fk' in line 984 of the addon's ui.py.  i dunno what ops.py is trying to do with it though.

so unless rigify has a script to update an extant generated rig...  i guess i'm trying to regenerate from the meta (if i find it or recreate it.)

thanks!